# Force Filewave verification

Tags: macos, shell, mdm, kernel-extension

I'm looking for a way to force a client computer to verify with our MDM filewave server preferably inside a script. Right now the only non gui way I have to force a verify on the client end, is by killing the fwcld service. This works well when ran directly on the client machine, but does not work when ran as a fileset from the filewave server.

The reason I need this, is because Kernel extension policies hang at "Handled via MDM" and will not activate until the next verification. This is way too slow when software is dependent on the kernel extension to install.

If anyone has a solution, either a script, or some other way to make the policy install quicker. I'd really appreciate. I've been banging my head against the wall for too long, the wall is looking pretty rough.

Answer (score 0):

According to FileWave's documentation MDM-managed clients auto-verify with the FileWave server, based on the "tickle interval".

[“waits for a specified amount of time (Tickle Interval … ) before it tries to connect again.”](https://fwkb.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/MAN/pages/4719097/4.1.+Understanding+FileWave+Clients+Groups+and+Smart+Groups)

By default this value is set to 120sec. The tickle interval can be changed by using the "SuperPrefs Editor". When using the SuperPrefs Editor **only** modify the values that you want to change.

Use these instructions to help you upload and apply the new FWpreferences to the (necessary) FileWave clients.
[Link to Knowledgebase](https://fwkb.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KB/pages/4332796/Creating+a+Superprefs+Fileset)

**FileWave has moved the Knowledgebase. All links above have been updated. 9/21/22 **

Comment: However before you go through all this work, try having the user log out & then wait 2min for the client to verify with the server. Perhaps the "Kernel extension" payload cannot be executed while a user is logged in. Also, have you tried the obvious troubleshoot step (rebooting the effected clients)?